# Sublime Typescript Undo Build Files

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

I accidentally clicked CTRL + B and it generated all JavaScript files and source map files from Typescript.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to undo this, as Sublime is constantly generating/updating the JS files whenever I update the Typescript files.

I am currently using Sublime 3 and Typescript with Angular 2 + Webpack.

Comment: i'm facing same problem hope someone answer soon

Answer (score 1):

If you are using git for version control, and don't have any other untracked files added, you can run:

`git clean -fd` which will remove all untracked files